# How to align a text outside and below a box?

Tags: html, css

So, I'm taking a course in TOP its basically a about web development. Right now I'm working in a project that the website wants me to do.

I've been facing a problem lately regarding aligning a text outside and below a box (div).

```css
 .title{
    text-align: center;
    font-size:36px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #1F2937;
    margin-top: 45px;
}

    .second_container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /* align-items: center; */
    padding: 30px 0px;
    gap:32px; 
}

    .image{
    border: 4px solid dodgerblue;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

    span.txt{
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
    Some random Information.
</div>
<div class="second_container">
    <div class="image">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <span class="txt">This is some subtext under an illustration
            or image.
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <span class="txt">This is some subtext under an illustration
            or image.
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <span class="txt">This is some subtext under an illustration
            or image.
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <span class="txt">This is some subtext under an illustration
            or image.
        </span>
    </div>
</div> <!--end of the random info container-->
```

I'm always getting the text inside the box. But I need the text outside and below it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text is nested in `.image` which has the border so it will always be inside without `absolute` positioning. Put the `border` on where the `img` will be, in this case, `.img`. Then the text will flow underneath.

```css
.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #1F2937;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.second_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* align-items: center; */
  padding: 30px 0px;
  gap: 32px;
}

.img {
  border: 4px solid dodgerblue;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

.image {
  width: 150px;
}

span.txt {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!--start of the random info container-->
<div class="title">
  Some random Information.
</div>
<div class="second_container">
  <div class="image">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <span class="txt">This is some subtext under an illustration or image.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <span class="txt">This is some subtext under an illustration or image.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <span class="txt">This is some subtext under an illustration or image.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <span class="txt">This is some subtext under an illustration or image.</span>
  </div>
</div>
<!--end of the random info container-->
```